# Sharing a common schematic among multiple boards in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Is it possible to share a single schematic among multiple boards in Altium?

In the old days when schematic capture and PCB layout were more separate, it was more obvious how to do this. How about now?

This is a design that over time there may be a dozen variants of the PCB, which differ only in the number of driver chips and shape.  Thus:

```
Power Supply Schematic + CPU Schematic + Driver Schematic for L shaped board  => L Shaped PCB
Power Supply Schematic + CPU Schematic + Driver Schematic for Z shaped board  => Z Shaped PCB
Power Supply Schematic + CPU Schematic + Driver Schematic for circle shaped board => Circle Shaped PCB
```

Comment: There is specific support for design variants in Altium.  See https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/design-variants-ad

Answer (score 0):

You can r-clk on a project folder and add existing files to it. The files should be updated in all projects where it is used once saved.

[image]